# Excel formula to modify the percentages (say discount) so that final sum after the discount is within the budget

Tags: excel-formula, percentage

After applying discounts `(x%,2x%,3x%)` to premium, the final discounted premium price is **1.1 million**. But maximum final discounted premium price that I can give is **1 Million**. Now, how to adjust the discounts `(x%,2x%,3x%)`, so that my final discounted prices is exactly **1M**

Note: I have to use only these 3 discounts `x%, 2x%, 3x%`

*e.g:*
[image: []

Comment: updated image to include only sample. Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this is your data :

[image: Data]

Formula in cell D2 to get the correct percentage :

```
=IF(AND(C2<2000,AND(B2>5000,B2<7000)),OFFSET($H$1,1,0),IF(AND(C2<2000,AND(B2>7000,B2<9000)),OFFSET($H$1,2,0),IF(AND(C2<2000,B2>9000),OFFSET($H$1,3,0),0)))
```

Formula in cell E2 to calculate the discounted premium :

```
=B2*(1-(D2/100))
```

Formula in cell H2 :

```
=5+H7
```

H7 contains the value we have to modify to increase the discount rates and get the desired final sum.

Formula in cell H9 :

```
=SUM(E2:E21)
```

Supposing we want a final sum equals to 125000. We use a dedicated function of Excel to do this. In "Data" tab, we select "What if analysis" then "Target value search". We input :

[image: Scenar]

We obtain the value to add to the discount rates to get a total sum of 125000 :

[image: Final]

[Sheet](https://drop.infini.fr/r/0ywthzrok6#mwsJnbMceqLvdENO4yQbxBVpAZYLSY6cOlKiX9A75MQ=)

Comment: Thank you.. I did all except Data tab - What IF part. I didn't knew about that feature.. Thanks a lot for sharing such a cool inbuilt function. This is really helpful...